# Alexa skill causes echo dot to become unresponsive

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on an Alexa skill that works fine when run using the ASK CLI `ask dialog`, but when I try to test on an echo dot or echosim.io, the skill launches but then doesn't respond to any inputs. I can't even say "Alexa stop" or "Alexa cancel". None of the inputs that work in the simulator work at all. Eventually the skill will reprompt me and then it will just error out with a little beep sound. No cloudwatch logs are created (even though the launch request appears to be successful because the launch response is played).

Here is my launch request handler:

```
const sound = require('../utils/sound');
const getUserFromHandler = require('../queries/getUserFromHandler');

module.exports = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },

  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const { wordIndex } = await getUserFromHandler(handlerInput);
    const welcomeMessage = `
      Welcome to skill name.
      ${wordIndex > 0 ? `You have learned ${wordIndex} word${wordIndex > 1 ? 's' : ''} so far, Good Job!` : ''}
      ${sound('choose-path-english')}
    `;

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(welcomeMessage)
      .reprompt(sound('choose-path-english'))
      .withSimpleCard('Welcome to skill name', 'Say "new word", "review", or "repeat word"')
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

The message "Welcome to skill name" and the audio file "choose-path-english" both get played as expected, but then no matter what I say, the echo dot just hangs waiting for a response.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you fix your issue by now or is it still a problem?

Comment: @andrew The issue was caused by having too many literal slots (it seems at some arbitrary number Alexa just stops working correctly). I ended up having to refactor my skill to use a single `AMAZON.SearchQuery` slot for multiple prompts instead of using 1 slot per prompt.